# Why does this extension method work with generics but not a set base type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

In my project I have the following class structure:

```
public interface IUpdateableModel
{
    ModelState State { get; set; }
    void ResetState();
}

public abstract class UpdateableModel : IUpdateableModel
{
    public ModelState State { get; set; }
    public void ResetState()
    {
        //Perform reset logic
    }
}

public class MyUpdateableClass : UpdateableModel
{
    //Some properties.
}
```

Now I am trying to add some extension methods for use with collections of `IUpdateable`:

```
public static class UpdateableModelExtensions
{
    public static bool HasUnsavedChanges(this IList<IUpdateableModel> collection)
    {
        return collection.Any(x => x.State != ModelState.Unmodified);
    }

     public static void ResetItemStates<T>(this IList<T> collection) where T : IUpdateableModel
    {
        var itemsToRemove = collection.Where(x => x.State == ModelState.New).ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
        {
            collection.Remove(item);
        }

        var itemsToAdd = collection.Where(x => x.State == ModelState.Deleted).ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
        {
            item.State = ModelState.Unmodified;
        }

        var itemsToReset = collection.Where(x => x.State == ModelState.Modified).ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemsToReset)
        {
            item.ResetState();
        }
    }
}
```

As written when using this on a `List<MyUpdateableClass>` a compiler error is produced that the types do no match up.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IList<MyUpdateableClass> Items {get; set;}

    public void MyMethod()
    {
         if(Items.HasUnsavedChanges()) //Compiler error
         {
            //Do some stuff
         }
    }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
 'IList<MyUpdateableModel>' does not contain a definition for
 'HasUnsavedChanges' and the best extension method overload
 'UpdateableModelExtensions.HasUnsavedChanges(IList<IUpdateableModel>)'
 requires a receiver of type 'IList<IUpdateableModel>'
```

The same result is seen if the extension method is changed to `IList<UpdateableModel>`

However if I instead use generics to implement this, it works fine:

```
public static bool HasUnsavedChanged<T>(this IList<T> collection) 
where T : IUpdateableModel
    {
        return collection.Any(x => x.State != ModelState.Unmodified);
    }
```

Also If I change the usage to `Items.Cast<IUpdateableModel>().ToList()` the first version does work.

So what are the technical details  that allow the generic version to work when the concrete version does not?

Comment: In what line the compiler gives the error?

Comment: Try "this IEnumerable<IUpdateableModel> collection" - this should work without generics because of covariance of IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @Dmitry i have confirmed that does not work, and there is another extension method that requires multiple enumerations so is not an option.

Comment: @Gusman I am typing up an edit to the more details on the usage

Comment: Ideally, provide an [mcve]. It's entirely understandable that you're getting an error at the moment, as a `List<ImplementationOfUpdateableModel>` is *not* an `IList<IUpdateableModel>`, but with a parameter of type `IEnumerable<IUpdateableModel>` it should work... at least if you're using .NET 4.0 or later.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry about that, I sometimes find it hard to get the assumptions out of my head. I think I've added everything pertinent at this point.

Comment: No, there's no indication that Dmitry's comment wouldn't work - and there still isn't a [mcve] - instead there are snippets. I would still expect just changing to `IEnumerable<IUpdateableModel>` to work.

Comment: @Dmitry My apologies given my first sample you were in fact correct that changing to IEnumerable would work.  I've added the other extension method that I mentioned as an example where I can't make this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the IList contents are more specific than the signature allows. This could result in a violation of the implied contract.

The contract of `IList<IUpdateableModel>` is that any implementer of `IUpdateableModel` must be able to be added to the list. This is not possible for a `List<ImplementationOfUpdateableModel>`  since you could only add objects of type `ImplementationOfUpdateableModel`.

The generic version works because it allows the method to accept ILists of more specific object contents.

Comment: That makes sense for some reason i wasn't connecting those dots.

Comment: I think the statement "This could result in a violation of the implied contract." should be reworded as "This does lead to a violation of the explicit contract."